# Setting values of a text view with a field of an object that is not available in the same class

Tags: java, android

I have an object of a class called ship1 which has an integer called addSpend and i also have a text view in another class. I want the text view to set its text to the object ship1's addSpend integer value. addSpend is *not* static. The object is in a ***Seperate*** class from the text view. So how do i set the text views text to the Ship1's int value called addSpend. They are in ***seperate*** classes.

here is the text view code:

```
TextView2.setText( new HangarActivity().getShip1().getAddSpend());
// I tried making a getter to get the object and then get its addSpend value but the app just crashed
// (i removed the getShip1 method from the class the objects in and i left it here to show
```

Here is the object code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

    hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

               Intent sendListEvents = new Intent();
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    ship1 = new Ship();
                    ship1.setAddAmount(10);
                    ship1.setAddTime(5000);
                    ship1.setAddSpend(100);
                    ship1.shipAdd();

                }
}
```

Comment: Dont do new HangarActivity() try to use the same HangarActivity that was created for your ship if you don't have it try to pass it in from the constructor.

Comment: you need to look into how you are storing your data ( model ) and how your Activity ( controller ) access that data into to show the data in your ListView ( view ).   Maybe have a GameEngine class that your activity gets a reference to, and the GameEngine holds the Ship objects you want to display

Comment: but how would i send the data to the other class